# CSS multiple classes on the same row in the stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I am still learning CSS and web development in general and have a basic understanding of how to create things with HTML/CSS. When looking around other peoples code/templates I often found this sort of structure in the CSS:

```
.grandparent .parent .child {
    some: style;
}
```

My understanding is that this applies to elements with class `child` AND has the parent class `parent` AND has the grandparent class `grandparent`. Like this:

```
<div class="grandparent">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            Some text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the style would NOT apply if the structure was something like this:

```
<div class="grandparent">
    <div class="some-other-class">
        <div class="child">
            Some text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, often I find that there is only one instance of the class `child` in the entire HTML document and to me it therefore seems unnecessary to declare it in the CSS with parents and grandparents and you could instead just write:

```
.child {
    some: style;
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is there any performance gains from doing it either way?
2. Is that just how you are supposed to declare CSS classes from a semantic point of view?
3. Did I just find people who write unneccesary long CSS declarations?

Comment: One cannot draw any conclusions about the motivation of those that wrote the selectors. The selectors are not necessarily right or wrong.

Comment: @Alohci, but one can answer the questions I asked given the facts that the class was only used at one place in the code? Maybe question 3 is hard to answer but the other 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the class names before the `.child` class name makes the selector more specific. More specific selectors will overwrite less specific selectors.

For example:

All `.child` elements will have the red color, except the one with the parent element with the class `option-green` because there is a more specific selector for that case.

```css
.child {
  color: red;
}

.option-green .child {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
     <li>
        <div class="child">Option 1</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="child">Option 2</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="child">Option 3</div>
      </li>
      <li class="option-green">
        <div class="child">Option 4</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="child">Option 5</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answers to your questions:

1. having less nested selector will be quicker of course.
2. start with simple selectors first and make them more specific when needed.
3. can be, sometimes people change code and forgot to update the CSS for example.

Also note that it isn't necessary that the specific parent needs the class name. For example, the following `.child` element will also have the green color set:

```
<div class="option-green">
  <div>
    <div><i><span class="child">I'm green!</span></i></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't have to use a jsfiddle. Use the `<>` button to create a snippet that runs in SO.

Comment: Thx, It's a long time I answered something on SO, updated it to use the SO one.

Comment: Okay so if I just have .child at 1 place in the HTML and will not use any more of it in other cases then the code I got was unneccessarily complicated and slower than removing the parents? Thank you for a good answer :)

Comment: @eligolf sounds like it ;) You're welcome :)

Comment: I wouldn't say that's unneccessary. Imagine if you have a group of developers working independently. If one group comes up with the same class name as another they would style each other's components accidentally. Or just one developer forgetting they used it somewhere else before.

Comment: @PeterKrebs, I understand, I meant in my specific private project with the conditions mentioned in the question :)

Comment: Yes sure for small projects not a problem. Big projects have another trick: Using just one class but having all parents as prefixes. So using `.option_green-child` would mean you only have to give the innermost element the class to style it. This is mainly used with a CSS preprocessor like [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/guide). Also for medium size projects and above but cool to learn.